# Why does it only scroll part of the way?

Tags: css, scroll

Implementing a navigation 'link' in a React app that looks something like this:

```
<div
    onClick={() => window.location.replace('#about-section')} 
>
about
</div>
```

Ive I've added {scroll-behavior: smooth} to html in the parent-most stylesheet and {scroll-snap-type: y mandatory} in the CSS for the parent element. And {scroll-snap-align: center;} on the child with the id of 'about-section'. When clicked once, it scrolls about 3/4 of the way there and then all the way on a second click. Any insight on the cause of such behavior?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out. There are elements between where I was scrolling from and where I wanted to scroll to, that are only rendered when visible by intersection observer. So as the scroll was happening, new elements were being rendered, throwing off the browser's calculation of how far to scroll. I gave the empty divs that are the parents of the not yet rendered elements an approximated min-height, and that worked!